# Can a database be replicated by the call of a procedure?

Tags: mysql, database

Following is a brief description of what is required.

1. We want to create a database and the contents(tables, procedures, functions, etc.) of this database should be the same as in another source database.
2. Point 1 should happen by a procedure call. It means, if we pass the database name to a procedure as an input parameter and execute the procedure, the database should be created with the same data as in another source database.
3. There is no issue in the creation of the database, but the issue occurs when we want to point to the newly created database. If our new database is, say testdb and when we give "USE testdb" for the execution of a script, it fails.
4. We used dynamic SQL but "USE" cannot be called in dynamic SQL.
5. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `USE` statement if you reference all tables and functions in your database using [qualified identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

That said, in my opinion replicating a database using a stored procedure is not a good solution. Why not just use `mysqldump`?

MySQL stored procedures are useful for very few purposes. Almost every task you might do with a stored procedure is easier to implement with client code, or existing tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! There are some limitations. 1) The database name is based on a user's input and there are 100+ tables, procedures, etc. to be created. So, using dynamic SQL to pass the database name as a qualified identifier is highly complex. 2) We want to replicate the database after a user's action is done and is not done using Workbench.

Comment: I mean the [mysqldump command-line tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/mysqldump.html), not Workbench. You haven't mentioned what client programming language you are using, but every language I know of can execute a command as a subprocess.

Comment: Thanks again! We are using Angular for UI and Node for the middle layer. We want the replication to be done after a user performs an action. So we want this to happen via a procedure call.

Comment: Okay, the only way you can use a procedure for this is to use qualified identifiers. I understand that you think this is complex, but it's really just string-concatenation. I suggested an alternative that would be very much not complex (`mysqldump`), but you are committed to the idea of doing this in a procedure. So you're back to the qualified identifiers as the only solution. Good luck!